SUMIFS is not working in pivot in googlesheets
This is my sample sheet. I pivot the Tradelog and want to have Net Units as BUY-SELL, but sumifs statement is giving a Arguments must be range error
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TwjrquwLlXL8AoEE91Yh-Vg56W7pZTbo5qq1lUVSWhU/edit?gid=1852104481#gid=1852104481
